# same object but one property value is missing

Tags: php

I have a strange problem recently,  same object but one property value is missing, on settter method on this property is called.  any reason why does this happen?

```
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'get--->' (length=7)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'userId:6' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '0000000058b398cc0000000054844e07' (length=32)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:int 2
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '<----get' (length=8)
vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorage.php:42:int 2
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'get--->' (length=7)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'userId:6' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '0000000058b398cc0000000054844e07' (length=32)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:int 2
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '<----get' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'get--->' (length=7)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'userId:6' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '0000000058b398cc0000000054844e07' (length=32)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:int 2
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '<----get' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'get--->' (length=7)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'userId:6' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '0000000058b398cc0000000054844e07' (length=32)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:int 2
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '<----get' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'get--->' (length=7)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string 'userId:6' (length=8)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '0000000058b398cc0000000054844e07' (length=32)
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:null
OrganizationAwareTrait.php:20:string '<----get' (length=8)
```

OrganizationTrait

```
trait OrganizationAwareTrait
{
    /**
     * @var OrganizationInterface
     *
     */
    private $organization;

    /**
     * @return OrganizationInterface|null
     */
    public function getOrganization()
    {
            var_dump('get--->','userId:'.$this->getId(), spl_object_hash($this), $this->organization? $this->organization->getId(): null, '<----get');

        return $this->organization;
    }

    /**
     * @param OrganizationInterface|null $organization
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOrganization(?OrganizationInterface $organization)
    {
         var_dump('set--->', $this->getId(), spl_object_hash($this), $organization? $organization->getId(): null, '<----get');

        $this->organization = $organization;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

User.php,  the serialize and unserialize of the user class are also not called.

```
class User {
use OrganizationTrait;

protected $otherPropertiesAreFine;

}
```

Comment: Who said it is the [same](http://php.net/spl_object_hash) object? `var_dump(spl_object_hash(new stdClass()), spl_object_hash(new stdClass()));` - `string(32) "00000000028ab2da000000006e9589e2" string(32) "00000000028ab2da000000006e9589e2" `

Comment: hi, the object hash is the same.

Comment: Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: @VidyVideni From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php): **Once the object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects.**

Comment: I see,  the second  object might use the previous object hash.